# Create and Execute XCOPY from SQL Temp Table?

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables, xcopy

I have a temp table that I fill with values like so:

```
FName   Project Plan    OriginalDoc NewDocName
Doe, John   ABC X   \\Path1\2\3.doc xyz1
Doe, John   ABC X   \\Path2\2\3.doc xyz2
Doe, John   ABC Y   \\Path3\2\3.doc xyz3
Doe, John   DEF X   \\Path4\1\3.doc xyz4
Doe, John   DEF Y   \\Path2\1\1.doc xyz5
Smith, Abbie    ABC X   \\Path2\5\3.doc xyz6
Smith, Abbie    DEF Y   \\Path4\2\4.doc xyz7
Smith, Abbie    GHI Y   \\Path231\22\13.doc xyz8
Smith, Abbie    GHI Y   \\Path11\22\33.doc  xyz9
Smith, Abbie    GHI Y   \\Path2345\34534\545.doc    xyz10
```

I want to create an xcopy statement from each row, and execute it.  Is this possible?

The xcopy would be something like this:

```
XCOPY Chr(34) + @OriginalDoc Chr(34) + ' ' + Chr(34) + '\\Server\PathA\PathB\' + @Project + '\' + @Fname + + '\' + @NewDocName + '.doc' + Chr(34)
```

Does that make sense?  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use xp_cmdshell for this.

Comment: Thanks.  I found that, but I am unsure of going through the temp table records.  I am starting with a while loop, but if I do a select on the temp table, working with a counter, and I get 1 record each loop, how do I call the temp table column name into that sql statement I need to generate/build?